# How do I delay a function call?

Tags: jquery

How do I delay my function (beginUpload()) from executing when it is called? I tried the function delay(), but the function still executes instantly after my form is submitted. I don't want the function to execute over and over on an interval. I just want to delay its execution for a period of time. Anyone have any ideas?

```
<form action="testing12345.php" target="progressFrame" method="post" id="uploadform" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="beginUpload().delay(8000);">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take it out of your DOM and use setTimeout:

HTML:

```
<form action="testing12345.php" target="progressFrame" method="post" id="uploadform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

JQuery:

```
$('#uploadForm').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the actual form submission so the page remains.
    var sub = setTimeout(function(){
        beginUpload();
    },8000);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

`setTimeout(beginUpload, 8000);return false;`

You need to return false to stop the browser submitting the form.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript setTimeout function is what you are after. You can call it in the form tag itself e.g.

```
<form action="testing12345.php" target="progressFrame" method="post" id="uploadform" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="setTimeout(beginUpload(), 2000);">
```

where 2000 = 2 seconds

or you could use it a similar way inside the beginUpload method

Answer (score 0):

`.delay` will not prevent the submit from happening.

```
onsubmit="setTimeout(beginUpload, 8000), return false;"
```

Comment: Sorry buddy I didn't downvote you. Thanks for the contribution I brought you back to 0 lol.